# Visio exporting drops empty fields when using external data (from Sharepoint List)

Tags: sharepoint, visio

I'm pretty new to Visio, so this terminology may not be right. 
I'm creating an office seating chart that uses a Sharepoint List as external data. Everything is working great, except when there is no employee that corresponds (via "Room ID") for a given shape. 
When I save as a Web Drawing, then update the List to add an employee to a given Room ID, and then Refresh, the new employee's name does not show up. Every other permutation works, i.e. swapping existing employees, deleting employees. It looks like Visio sees an empty field and just deletes its reference.
My workaround has been to have a dummy employee in every vacant spot when I save out the Visio file, and then go in and delete them. Upon refresh, it looks good.
My question is: can I accomplish this a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The occupier of a space could be assigned in your external list. So have all of the space Ids linked, and the occupier id, and related info, are just columns in the view. (The space id is the key field).